# setopt does not work in .zshrc. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration

This is what I have in `~/.zshrc` (actually a file sourced from my `~/.zshrc`, see below).

```
#CHANGING DIRECTORIES
setopt CD_SILENT
setopt CDABLE_VARS
setopt AUTO_CD

#COMPLETION
setopt recexact autolist listambiguous menucomplete hashlistall globcomplete completeinword completealiases autoparamslash  

#EXPANSION AND GLOBBING
setopt nomatch badpattern globstarshort rcexpandparam extendedglob nocaseglob numericglobsort markdirs

#HISTORY
SAVEHIST=8192
HISTSIZE=$(( 1.2 * SAVEHIST ))
HISTFILE="$ZDOTDIR/.zhistory" 
setopt nohistbeep extendedhistory histverify sharehistory histallowclobber histreduceblanks histfcntllock histignoredups histignorealldups histsavenodups

#SCRIPTS AND FUCNTIONS
setopt multios aliasfuncdef localoptions localloops localtraps cbases cprecedences

#MISC
setopt transientrprompt nocheckjobs ignoreeof nobeep nolistbeep nonotify noclobber interactivecomments
```

Nothing works except the `HISTFILE` setting.

```
% setopt
interactive
monitor
shinstdin
zle
```

```
% ls .zhistory
.zhistory
```

However, if I use `setopt autocd` inside the terminal it works for that session. Here is an example:

```
% setopt
interactive
monitor
shinstdin
zle
% setopt autocd
% setopt
autocd
interactive
monitor
shinstdin
zle
```

If I add `echo I AM BEING LOADED, EVEN THEN I FAIL TO LOAD ANY SETOPT COMMANDS` to that `.zshrc`, upon startup, I do see:

```
I AM BEING LOADED, EVEN THEN I FAIL TO LOAD ANY SETOPT COMMANDS
% setopt
interactive
monitor
shinstdin
zle
```

That's with zsh 5.9 on GNU/Linux amd64.

The file is actually sourced with:

```
# FUNCTOIN TO SOURCE READABLE FILES
function src {
[[ -r "$1" ]] && source "$1"
}

if [[ -d ~/.config/.zshell/zload.d/ ]]; then
for FileToLoad in ~/.config/.zshell/zload.d/*.zsh(n); do
src "$FileToLoad"
done
unset FileToLoad
fi

unset -f src
```

Comment: Have you looked into this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347739/setopt-listambiguous-not-setting-the-option
It seems setopt won't show list options that are on their default value.

Comment: I think you have not seen the code. I do not think all the options I am adding is activated by default. If I manually use setopt autocd in the terminal it shows up. 
I will update the post and add a photo so that you can understand

Comment: What happens if you use, `setopt auocd` instead of `setopt AUTO_CD`?  I can't find any references to the later.

Comment: @thomas Seems like there is a missing `t` in there: `s/auocd/autocd/`

Comment: Hi, Thomas autocd and AUTO_CD are the same. it parses like zsh shell is supposed to. it ignores capitalization and underscores. I have tried AUTO_CD/autocd it does not change anything.

Comment: In the zsh options manual, just below **Changing Directories** there is an entry for `AUTO_CD`. @Thomas

Comment: @Pragmatic Is `.zshrc` being loaded for non-interactive zsh shells?

Comment: @QuartzCristal I do not think so. I have this line at the very top [ ! -o interactive ]] && return

Comment: @Pragmatic Please add as the first line in `.zshrc` the command `echo loading .zshrc` and start a new zsh session (just execute `zsh` on the command line). Is `.zshrc` being loaded ?

Comment: Then, there is no reason for the options to not being loaded. The file is being executed (sourced) and the options should take hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry guys I misunderstood the use of `setopt localoptions`.
Please note that I am learning so mistakes can happen.
That is the reason I was having the issue. That was a dumb mistake lol

Nothing was working and it was making me mad. So, I decided to revisit the basics at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html

To debug the solution that I concocted for myself. I turned on `setopt xtrace` to see if those lines were being read. Here is the output:
[image]

You can see here that nothing is wrong with the shell and every line is being read. From there trial and error can lead you to the solution.

Once I realized commenting out `localoptions` solves all my issues. I went and read what it does again and realized that my comprehension of it was wrong. To know what the option does you can visit the above shared link.

Here, as `setopt localoptions` was done from within the `src` function, all option settings were made local to that function.

Here is a photo that shows that it is now working:
[image]
P.S-> I did not figure it out by myself actually, someone in the zsh forum helped me get there.

My zsh version:
[image: zsh version]